# Does the Black Bullet anime cover the whole light novel and/or manga?

Tags: black-bullet

Aside from the anime, *Black Bullet* has a light novel which started the franchise and a manga.

Does watching only the anime get to know the whole story or not? Does the 13 episodes anime cover the whole light novel and/or manga?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The *Black Bullet* anime covers the first 4 volumes of the light novel, while the manga covers the first volume.**

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%96%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%88#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88),

> - Episode 1-4: Volume 1
> - Episode 5-7: Volume 2
> - Episode 8-10: Volume 3
> - Episode 11-13: Volume 4

Also according to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%96%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%88#%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB), the manga is based on the first volume of the light novel.

However, the light novel has passed the 4th volume (as of current: 7 volumes).